# Spring boot run multiple applications

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have one project with multiple modules, every module itself is spring boot application. I need to run all this applications with one command(using .bat for windows OR one maven run), how can I do it?

Project structure looking like this:

```
/base-app
  /auth-service
     /pom.xml - child pom
  /eureka-service
     /pom.xml
  /zuul-service
     /pom.xml
pom.xml - main pom
```

I can't understand at all how to do it with maven. But I tried to do it with .bat file like this:

```
call mvn -f eureka-service/pom.xml spring-boot:run
call mvn -f zuul/pom.xml spring-boot:run
```

First "call" worked fine, but second one was ignored.
I need this to fast start all my services.

Comment: The second call, it looks like you don't have the correct directory? `zuul` vs `zuul-service`

Answer (score 2):

This smells monolith all over. I can't really justify use of a parent pom, in a microservice world (arguable). This is just my honest opinion, your scenario might be totally different.

That being said, I believe, each of the child projects (auth-service,euraka and zuul) are creating it's own artifacts (jars). If yes, you can just do `java -jar` on each of that in your .bat or shell commands.

Comment: and what about spring-boot, is there a way to run it using maven? I know this not best idea, but it's not production and this is needed for testing and easier development.

Comment: @Evgenii . If they are Spring Boot apps you can do:  mvn spring-boot:run If you need to have a single script do it you will have to use nohup or something to keep each of these commands running in their own process.

Answer (score 0):

If you run each of your services in a separate Docker container, Docker Compose will do what you're looking for and bring up all the services in their containers in one command with:

```
docker-compose up
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/